# get selected checkbox from child component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

i'm showing up all category and subcategory with recursive component. i want to get all selected categor's id in parent component.

in my code when i select sub cat it does not return anything how can i fix this?

you can see live example here

https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-waterfall-3cpfe?file=/src/App.vue

**parent component.**

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
      <Child :cats.sync="selectedCategories" :categories="categories"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  data: function() {
    return {
      categories: [
        { id: 1, name: "Category 1", children: [
          {id: 11, name:"sub1", children: [
            {id: 111, name: "sub 2", children: []}
            ]}
            ] },
        { id: 2, name: "Category 2", children: [] },
        { id: 3, name: "Category 3", children: [] }
      ],
      selectedCategories: []
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

**child component:**

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <label v-for="c in categories" :key="c.id">
      <input v-model="temp" type="checkbox" :value="c">
      {{ c.name }}

      <template v-if="c.children.length > 0">
            <Child :categories="c.children" />
      </template>

    </label>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Child",
  props: {
    categories: Array,
    cats: Array
  },
  computed: {
    temp: {
      get: function() {
        return this.cats;
      },
      set: function(newValue) {
        this.$emit("update:cats", newValue);
      }
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not work because you are binding subcategories with `<HelloWorld v-model="temp" :categories="c.children" />` instead of `<HelloWorld :cats.sync="temp" :categories="c.children" />`